# In which class "should" the responsiblity lie in fetching the data from the Data access layer (RDD)

Tags: oop, class-design, rdd, solid-principles

Lets say I have a class representing a course.The course has its own attributes like subject name, descriprion, start- and an ending date and so on.

Then, the course has attributes like a list of participants. In the database this is obviously represented in two classes; the course and a participant table in a one-to-may relationship.

My question is about how to set the list of participant in the course class: Should it be the course class itself that is fetching the data (through a data access layer, or a layer above), or should one delegate the fetching and the setting of the participants to some kind of helper class, making the course class it's self more or less a dumb object, only holding data?

In RDD(Resopnsible driven design) it tells us to make smart object and abstract away the differentce between data and behaviours. In this regards it sounds obvious that the course class should handle the fetching of the participants. Doing this howerver, is creating a direct dependence on a data access object (or a level above), making it more couple up.

Any thought on this would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to check out http://programmers.stackexchange.com it is big on design discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: @ChrisWohlert when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Sorry, I meant for future reference. I will keep this in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Should it be the course class itself that is fetching the data

This is a pattern known as [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). Be aware that many feel that active record is an [anti-pattern](http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-1-active-record/).

> or should one delegate the fetching and the setting of the participants to some kind of helper class

This is a pattern known as [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

> making the course class it's self more or less a dumb object, only holding data?

Removing the responsibility of saving and retrieving data from the entity doesn't make that entity a dumb object, only holding data. The entity can still hold domain logic, which is a common practice when practicing [Domain-Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). In DDD, entities as simple data containers without behavior are called [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

Comment: So in short, a good way to go is to use the Repository pattern?

Comment: @Fred: That's up to you. You should investigate in reading and understanding those patterns and make an educated decision.

Answer (score 0):

The Course class shouldn't be responsible for fetching the participants, in fact, it shouldn't be responsible for fetching the Courses. You bring up the correct point of data access layers, but the course class itself should not work with this layer, it must just represent a course.

You create a class which has the responsibility of fetching the data, i.e the data access layer. You can name this something similar to CourseDao, but the important part is; that it simply gets the data from the database, and returns it to the client as Courses. 
This class has methods like Create, Read, Update and Delete.

Now, you want to do the same for participants, with one small difference. Since your Participant table has a foreign key to Course, your ParticipantDao will have an overloaded Read.

Example:

```
public class ParticipantDao{
    public void create(Participant participant){
        //Insert participant in db
    }
    public Participant read(int id){
        //read participant from db
    }
    public List<Participant> read(){
        //read all participants from db
    }
    public List<Participant> read(Course course){
        //read all participants in this course from the db
    }
    public void Update(Participant participant){
        //update and so on.
    }
}
```

And your CourseDao can use this ParticipantDao by going something like:

```
foreach(Course course in read()){
    course.setParticipants(this.participantDao.read(course));
}
```

In short, you have an object to access the data in the database, which is not the same object that represents said data. When you have a One-To-Many relation, these access objects can work together to retrieve the correct data.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer! Then you could also have a "wrapper method" on a object above that fetches both course and participant data, which creates a course object with the participants, making it a "smart/domain object" while at the same time not being responsible for the fetching/setting of data..